# Filter multiple array with multiple conditions

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

This is my Array:

```
[
  [
   {
    id: 111,
    img_name: 'Image 1.jpg',
    img_url:'https://www.abc.png',
    show_img:true,
    publish:true
   }
  ],
  [],
  [
   {
    id: 333,
    img_name: 'Image 3.jpg',
    img_url:'https://www.ghi.png',
    show_img:false,
    publish:false
   }
  ]
]
```

UPDATE: Based on Mamun's answer this is the output I get

[]
[]
[]

And this is the output I need:

```
[
 {
   id: 111,
   img_name: 'Image 1.jpg',
   img_url:'https://www.abc.png',
   show_img:true,
   publish:true
 }
]
```

Now how do I filter the images based on the condition "show_img :true and "publish: true"

Comment: What's the output supposed to look like? Object arrays in an array or a one-dimensional array?

Comment: Yes I need object arrays in array

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `filter()` method.

```js
const array = [
  [
   {
    id: 111,
    img_name: 'Image 1.jpg',
    img_url:'https://www.abc.png',
    show_img:true,
    publish:true
   }
  ],
  [],
  [
   {
    id: 333,
    img_name: 'Image 3.jpg',
    img_url:'https://www.ghi.png',
    show_img:false,
    publish:false
   }
  ]
]

 //If you want to keep the structure of your initial array as it is then you can use this.
  const filterredArray = array.filter(item => item.length && item[0].show_img && item[0].publish);
 
 //If you want to flattern your array then use `flat()`
 const filterredflatternArray = array.flat().filter(item => item.show_img && item.publish);

 console.log("filterredArray", filterredArray);
 console.log("filterredflatternArray", filterredflatternArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

Code:

```js
const data = [
  [
    {
      id: 111,
      img_name: 'Image 1.jpg',
      img_url:'https://www.abc.png',
      show_img: true,
      publish: true
    }
  ],
  [],
  [
    {
      id: 333,
      img_name: 'Image 3.jpg',
      img_url:'https://www.ghi.png',
      show_img: false,
      publish: false
    }
  ]
];

const filteredImages = [];
data.forEach((sublist) => {
  sublist.forEach((image) => {
    if (image.show_img && image.publish) {
      filteredImages.push(image);
    }
  });
});

console.log(filteredImages);
```

Output

```
[
    {
        "id": 111,
        "img_name": "Image 1.jpg",
        "img_url": "https://www.abc.png",
        "show_img": True,
        "publish": True
    }
]
```

In the code snippet, `filteredImages` is an empty array initially. The `forEach()` method is used to iterate over each `sublist` in the data array. Within each `sublist`, the `forEach()` method is used again to iterate over each `image` object. The condition `if (image.show_img && image.publish)` checks if the `show_img` property is true and the `publish` property is true for each `image`. If the condition is satisfied, the `image` object is pushed into the `filteredImages` array.

Finally, the `filteredImages` array contains the filtered images that meet the specified conditions.